# PyCharm cannot access files in /usr/lib/ and /usr/bin/

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, pycharm, python-os

I am using **PyCharm 2020.2.3** with **Python 3.8.6** under Pop_OS! 20.10 (you can probably do as if I am using **Ubuntu 20.10**) which is unable to see files into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib`.

Here is an example if I try to touch the `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` binary file.

```
# main.py
import os
print(os.path.exists('/usr/lib'))
print(os.path.exists('/usr/lib/firefox'))
print(open('/usr/lib/firefox/firefox', 'r'))
```

From the command line, this works:

```
>>> python main.py
True
True
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/usr/lib/firefox/firefox' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

But when I run it in PyCharm, it fails like so:

```
True         # Can see /usr/lib
False        # Cannot see /usr/lib/firefox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line 5, in <module>
    print(open('/usr/lib/firefox/firefox', 'r'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/firefox/firefox'
```

Here are the permissions for `usr/bin/firefox`:

```
>>> ls -ld firefox
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Oct 26 10:22 firefox
```

There are numerous questions regarding similar issues but most of them end up suggesting a work around related to the specific file required.

There seem to be some kind of permission issue and I want to tackle that without having to rely on a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more than one month, I found [this thread on intellij-support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000919139-PyCharm-is-showing-python-3-7-but-python-3-5-is-installed-on-my-system) which explains the issue happens because I installed a PyCharm flatpack.

> I eventually figured out my issue was caused by how I installed
> pycharm.  I had used the app store which installs a flatpack.  Due to
> how flatpacks work, it installs an isolated environment containing
> everything the app needs.  With normal apps this could be useful at
> the expense of duplicate files using extra disk space, but for
> development apps it makes it so you can't run your code reliably from
> inside the flatpack installed app.
>
> -- Mvanorder1390 (Created October 30, 2019 13:13)

This was exactly my issue. I reinstalled PyCharm from the official source instead of my app-store which only offered a flatpack version and everything now works like a charm (pun intended)!

Comment: Dude, THANK YOU! I took me a day to find this post, but this was totally the cause! Cheers!

Comment: what really is the point of a having flatpack version that does not work with R plugin? it took me a day to find your solution for missing R interpretter. thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the problem persists in 2024. I installed it with jetbrains toolbox and it works perfectly.